# How to switch to AMD graphics with AMD RAVEN/NVIDIA dual graphics

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, nvidia-optimus, 19.10

I think my laptop, an Asus Rog Zephyrus G G4502, is unable correctly switch graphics card with `prime-select`. I'm trying to turn off the nvidia gpu for better battery life

**Edit 1**:
The power consumption after running `sudo prime-select nvidia && reboot` is **lower** than running `sudo prime-select intel && reboot`.

Software and Updates recognises the Nvidia card and drivers. Nvidia Settings currently gives me this:

```
(nvidia-settings:11339): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 14:27:26.898: g_object_unref: assertions 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
** Message: PRIME: No offloading required. Abort
** Message: PRIME: is it supported? no
```

I've tried to purge and reinstall nvidia drivers a dozen times(even clean installs).

Without `xorg.conf` file, nvidia-settings shows a blank screen.
With this file it shows some info about the gpu but no PRIME profiles tab.

**Edit 2**:
Output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'`:

```
victor7095@victor7095-Zephyrus-G-GU502DU-GA502DU:~$ lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU116M [GeForce GTX 1660 Ti Mobile] (rev a1)
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. TU116M [GeForce GTX 1660 Mobile]
Kernel driver in use: nvidia
Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
--
05:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Picasso (rev c1)
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Picasso
Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
Kernel modules: amdgpu
--
05:00.7 Non-VGA unclassified device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2/Renoir Non-Sensor Fusion Hub KMDF driver
Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2/Renoir Non-Sensor Fusion Hub KMDF driver
Kernel driver in use: i2c_amd_mp2
Kernel modules: i2c_amd_mp2_pci
```

Output of `mokutil --sb-state`:

```
victor7095@victor7095-Zephyrus-G-GU502DU-GA502DU:~$ mokutil --sb-state
SecureBoot enabled
```

**Edit 3**:
Output of `glxinfo | grep OpenGL`:

```
victor7095@victor7095-Zephyrus-G-GU502DU-GA502DU:~$ glxinfo | grep OpenGL
OpenGL vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
OpenGL renderer string: GeForce GTX 1660 Ti with Max-Q Design/PCIe/SSE2
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 440.44
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.60 NVIDIA
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 440.44
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.60 NVIDIA
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 NVIDIA 440.44
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

**Edit 4**:
Output of `xrandr --listproviders`:

```
victor7095@victor7095-Zephyrus-G-GU502DU-GA502DU:~$ xrandr --listproviders
Providers: number : 2
Provider 0: id: 0x1e8 cap: 0x1, Source Output crtcs: 4 outputs: 2 associated providers: 1 name:NVIDIA-0
Provider 1: id: 0x45 cap: 0x6, Sink Output, Source Offload crtcs: 4 outputs: 2 associated providers: 1 name:modesetting
```

**Edit 5**:
After @Pilot6 suggestions, I`m posting new output.

Output of `nvidia-smi`:

```
victor7095@victor7095-Zephyrus-G-GU502DU-GA502DU:~$ nvidia-smi
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

Output of `nvidia-settings`:

```
victor7095@victor7095-Zephyrus-G-GU502DU-GA502DU:~$ nvidia-settings

ERROR: NVIDIA driver is not loaded


ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system


(nvidia-settings:4070): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 15:58:56.780: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
** Message: 15:58:56.784: PRIME: No offloading required. Abort
** Message: 15:58:56.784: PRIME: is it supported? no
```

Output of `glxinfo | grep OpenGL`:

```
victor7095@victor7095-Zephyrus-G-GU502DU-GA502DU:~$ glxinfo | grep OpenGL
OpenGL vendor string: X.Org
OpenGL renderer string: AMD RAVEN (DRM 3.33.0, 5.3.0-24-generic, LLVM 9.0.0)
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 19.2.1
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.50
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 4.5 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 19.2.1
```

**Edit 6**:
Output of `dkms status`:

```
victor7095@victor7095-Zephyrus-G-GU502DU-GA502DU:~$ dkms status
nvidia, 440.44, 5.3.0-24-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8821ce, 5.2.5.2.1.30816.20190425, 5.3.0-24-generic, x86_64: installed
```

**Edit 6**:
Output of some bbswitch commands:

```
victor7095@victor7095-Zephyrus-G-GU502DU-GA502DU:/proc/acpi$ sudo cat /proc/acpi/bbswitch
cat: /proc/acpi/bbswitch: No such file or directory
victor7095@victor7095-Zephyrus-G-GU502DU-GA502DU:/proc/acpi$ sudo tee /proc/acpi/bbswitch <<<OFF
tee: /proc/acpi/bbswitch: No such file or directory
OFF
victor7095@victor7095-Zephyrus-G-GU502DU-GA502DU:/proc/acpi$ sudo modprobe bbswitch
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'bbswitch': No such device
```

Output of `dmesg | tail`:

```
victor7095@victor7095-Zephyrus-G-GU502DU-GA502DU:/proc/acpi$ dmesg | tail
[ 1153.397538] bbswitch: version 0.8
[ 1153.397556] bbswitch: Found discrete VGA device 0000:01:00.0: \_SB_.PCI0.GPP0.PEGP
[ 1153.397561] bbswitch: Found discrete VGA device 0000:05:00.0: \_SB_.PCI0.GP17.VGA_
[ 1153.397593] bbswitch: failed to evaluate \_SB_.PCI0.GP17.VGA_._DSM {0xF8,0xD8,0x86,0xA4,0xDA,0x0B,0x1B,0x47,0xA7,0x2B,0x60,0x42,0xA6,0xB5,0xBE,0xE0} 0x100 0x0 {0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00}: AE_NOT_FOUND
[ 1153.397605] bbswitch: failed to evaluate \_SB_.PCI0.GP17.VGA_._DSM {0xA0,0xA0,0x95,0x9D,0x60,0x00,0x48,0x4D,0xB3,0x4D,0x7E,0x5F,0xEA,0x12,0x9F,0xD4} 0x102 0x0 {0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00}: AE_NOT_FOUND
[ 1153.397606] bbswitch: No suitable _DSM call found.
```

Output of `dmesg | grep bbswitch`:

```
victor7095@victor7095-Zephyrus-G-GU502DU-GA502DU:/proc/acpi$ dmesg | grep bbswitch
[ 1153.397538] bbswitch: version 0.8
[ 1153.397556] bbswitch: Found discrete VGA device 0000:01:00.0: \_SB_.PCI0.GPP0.PEGP
[ 1153.397561] bbswitch: Found discrete VGA device 0000:05:00.0: \_SB_.PCI0.GP17.VGA_
[ 1153.397593] bbswitch: failed to evaluate \_SB_.PCI0.GP17.VGA_._DSM {0xF8,0xD8,0x86,0xA4,0xDA,0x0B,0x1B,0x47,0xA7,0x2B,0x60,0x42,0xA6,0xB5,0xBE,0xE0} 0x100 0x0 {0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00}: AE_NOT_FOUND
[ 1153.397605] bbswitch: failed to evaluate \_SB_.PCI0.GP17.VGA_._DSM {0xA0,0xA0,0x95,0x9D,0x60,0x00,0x48,0x4D,0xB3,0x4D,0x7E,0x5F,0xEA,0x12,0x9F,0xD4} 0x102 0x0 {0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00}: AE_NOT_FOUND
[ 1153.397606] bbswitch: No suitable _DSM call found.
```

Output of `dmesg | grep acpi`:

```
victor7095@victor7095-Zephyrus-G-GU502DU-GA502DU:/proc/acpi$ dmesg | grep acpi
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0xff] high edge lint[0x1])
[    0.132087] acpiphp: ACPI Hot Plug PCI Controller Driver version: 0.5
[    0.160775] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC: OS supports [ExtendedConfig ASPM ClockPM Segments MSI HPX-Type3]
[    0.160932] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC: platform does not support [SHPCHotplug LTR]
[    0.161083] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC: OS now controls [PCIeHotplug PME AER PCIeCapability]
[    0.161094] acpi PNP0A08:00: [Firmware Info]: MMCONFIG for domain 0000 [bus 00-3f] only partially covers this bridge
[    0.188199] clocksource: acpi_pm: mask: 0xffffff max_cycles: 0xffffff, max_idle_ns: 2085701024 ns
[    0.343322] acpi_cpufreq: overriding BIOS provided _PSD data
[    0.433812] acpi device:19: registered as cooling_device8
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102477/discussion-on-question-by-victor-yan-how-to-switch-to-amd-graphics-with-amd-rave).